# Node 14 ECMAScript Modules and Packages

Tags: javascript, node.js

In [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_terminology) for Node's native support of ECMAScript modules, they state

> There are three types of specifiers:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. Bare specifiers like 'some-package' or 'some-package/shuffle'. They can refer to the main entry point of a package by the package name, or a specific feature module within a package prefixed by the package name as per the examples respectively. Including the file extension is only necessary for packages without an "exports" field.
> 3. ...

The definition of bare specifiers indicate you can `import` ECMAScript Modules from "packages".

What's considered a "package" in Node.js?  Does node just search the entire `node_modules` folder for any folder with a package.json file and consider that a package?  Or is it more complicated than that? Is it the same for CommonJS modules and ESMAScript modules?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Comment: +1 Thank you @evert -- however that documentation appears to be for commonjs modules loaded via require.  I'm interested in ECMAScript modules loaded via import.  I've updated my question to make this point clearer.

Comment: Fair enough! A package is afaik just a directory in `node_modules`. However, I assume you are looking for a reference which I don't have.

Comment: @Evert ESM version: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#resolver-algorithm-specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's considered a "package" in Node.js?

In the sense of "bare" named packages for ESM, any name that matches a node builtin package, or is in `node_modules/{{ bare name }}` in the current directory or subsequently any parent directory, that has a `package.json` that loads and also has the correct `name` field.

> Does node just search the entire node_modules folder for any folder with a package.json file and consider that a package? Or is it more complicated than that?

Basically, node doesn't care about anything you haven't named as an import though. It's always more complicated, the algorithm is documented [further down on the ESM modules page](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_resolver_algorithm_specification).

> Is it the same for CommonJS modules and ESMAScript modules?

No, although the part that resolves the package exports is shared once a "package" is located and vetted by the [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_resolver_algorithm_specification) or [CommonJS rules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together)). Big differences are

- Global `node_modules` are not considered in ESM (i.e. traversing `$NODE_PATH`, `$HOME` and the node `$PREFIX`).

Outside of the process for loading this subset or "bare names" there are more differences.

- ESM modules or `mjs` files will not load via `require`.
- No native or JSON imports

Generally the ESM loader is a much more strict subset of CommonJS as anything Node specific doesn't apply.